# water effect wavy loading animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How I can create a water effect wavy loading animation in flutter ?

I want something like this

[image]

Comment: you can use a package like this and customize it as per your requirement. https://pub.dev/packages/waveprogressbar_flutter

Comment: @RTXGamer thanks

Comment: A more current package would be this one: https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_progress_indicator_v2

Answer (score 2):

#### AnimationController / CustomPainter solution

One solution it is to use a `CustomPainter` for drawing the wave, and creating a widget with a `AnimationController`. Then defining a `Tween` which is animated with the value provided from the animation controller. In the example below the tween is responsible for moving the wave leftward one wavelength as this would effectively loop the animation.

#### Example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: const [
          WaveBackground()
        ],
      )
    ),
  );
}

class WaveBackground extends StatefulWidget {
  const WaveBackground({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WaveBackground> createState() => _WaveBackgroundState();
}

class _WaveBackgroundState extends State<WaveBackground> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildAnimation(BuildContext context, Widget? widget) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: WavePainter(
            controller: _controller,
            waves: 2,
            waveAmplitude: 25
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: _buildAnimation,
    );
  }
}

class WavePainter extends CustomPainter {
  late final Animation<double> position;
  final Animation<double> controller;

  /// Number of waves to paint.
  final int waves;

  /// How high the wave should be.
  final double waveAmplitude;
  int get waveSegments => 2 * waves - 1;

  WavePainter({required this.controller, required this.waves, required this.waveAmplitude}) {
    position = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear))
        .animate(controller);
  }

  void drawWave(Path path, int wave, size) {
    double waveWidth = size.width / waveSegments;
    double waveMinHeight = size.height / 2;

    double x1 = wave * waveWidth + waveWidth/2;
    // Minimum and maximum height points of the waves.
    double y1 = waveMinHeight + (wave.isOdd ? waveAmplitude: -waveAmplitude);

    double x2 = x1 + waveWidth/2;
    double y2 = waveMinHeight;

    path.quadraticBezierTo(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    if (wave <= waveSegments) {
      drawWave(path, wave + 1, size);
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.lightBlue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    // Draw the waves
    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    drawWave(path, 0, size);

    // Draw lines to the bottom corners of the size/screen with account for one extra wave.
    double waveWidth = (size.width / waveSegments) * 2;
    path..lineTo(size.width + waveWidth, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height / 2)
      ..close();

    // Animate sideways one wave length, so it repeats cleanly.
    Path shiftedPath = path.shift(Offset(-position.value * waveWidth , 0));

    canvas.drawPath(shiftedPath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[image: Wave animation]

Comment: thanks, that is help full for me

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://pub.dev/packages/waveprogressbar_flutter) package does exactly what you need.
Keep in mind that it's **not** `null safety`.

Your best alternative is [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit) other package, that offers a lot of different animations.

Comment: thanks, that is help full for me